# Type definition for comparing (and updating) certain fields of objects in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typing

I'd like to compare and assign certain fields of two objects, let's say:

```
const left = { a: 1, ignored: 5, something: 7 };
const right = { a: 2, ignored: 6, else: 8, id: 18 };
```

And I want to call `leftToRight(left, right, ['a'])` after which `right` should be:

```
{ a: 1, ignored: 6, id: 18 }
```

and I want to call some other function and pass right.id, which I know does exists on the second argument.

My current approach is:

```
leftToRight(left, right, keys) {
  let changed = false;
  
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!Object.is(left[key], right[key])) {
      right[key] = left[key];
      changed = true;
    }
  }

  doSomething(right.id)

  return changed
}
```

I'm struggling to find the appropriate type definition :-(

Initial approach:

```
leftToRight<T>(left: T, right: T, keys: Array<keyof T>): boolean
```

leads to: "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'T'" and I found no way to check this (`'id' in right`)

Second attempt:

```
leftToRight<T>(left: T, right: T & {id: number}, keys: Array<keyof T>): boolean
```

leads to "Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ id: number; }'" for `right[key] = left[key]`

Third attempt:

```
leftToRight<T, U extends {id: number}>(left: T, right: U, keys: Array<keyof T & keyof U>): boolean
```

again leads to an error for the assignment `right[key] = left[key]` because the types T and U could be completely unrelated.

Comment: Is the `id` field supposed to be a `string` or a `number`?

Comment: I corrected the question. It's a number.

Comment: I would use `leftToRight<T>(left: T, right: T & {id: number}, keys: Array<keyof T>): boolean` and inside the implementation do `(right as T)[key] = left[key]` or something like it to get rid of that error; I'm looking for why the compiler has a problem assigning `T[keyof T]` to `(T & {id: number})[keyof T])`, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

You have clarified your requirements to say that `Left` and `Right` might each have properties which are not present in the other.  To handle this scenario, we need two generic types.

`Right` is an object which includes an `id`.  We want the selected keys to be present in both `Left` and `Right` and we want them to have the same value types.
I defined the generic `Keys` as any subset of the keys of `Right`.  I defined `Left` as the subset of `Right` containing all these keys.

```
function leftToRight<Right extends {id: number}, Keys extends keyof Right>(
  left: Pick<Right, Keys>, right: Right, keys: Keys[]
) {
  let changed = false;
  
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!Object.is(left[key], right[key])) {
      right[key] = left[key];
      changed = true;
    }
  }

  doSomething(right.id)

  return changed
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/aNn5Bw)

**Original Answer:**

I tried a few things before finding one that works.  Of course this is not the cleanest definition.  I got errors when using the generic to describe `Left` and adding `id` to get `Right`, but removing from `Right` works.

We say that `Right` is an object with an `{id: number}` property and `Left` must have all properties of `Right` except for `id`.  In order for the elements of `keys` to be present on both objects, we need to ignore the key `id` from `keyof Right`.

```
function leftToRight<Right extends {id: number}>(
  left: Omit<Right, 'id'>, right: Right, keys: (Exclude<keyof Right, 'id'>)[]
) {
  let changed = false;
  
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!Object.is(left[key], right[key])) {
      right[key] = left[key];
      changed = true;
    }
  }

  doSomething(right.id)

  return changed
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/lWY2Qw)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I wasn't clear enough in my question (will add it): `left` does not necessarily have all the properties of `right` (and vice versa).

Comment: Ok so `right` always has an `id`, `left` and `right` have any properties, and `keys` must only be shared properties, is that correct?  We would need (at least) two generics but I think I can do it.  I'll see...

Answer (score 0):

Try with `left: Partial<T>`, and assert that `left[key]` is not undefined with `!`.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgUwGawLwwN4wIYC4YCMANDAJYDmYIATggCb4CsAvgNwBQoks1FAFmkw58AJhIUqtBjABs46QQAcMNu3ZIArmGBRS4eMigAVEACV+UADxGAfAApEKfAAVs1XdjjWbJXuQH4RiQA1ggAnhD4AILU1NhhlqFhIEgwtgCUmOwwBrDAfNhg5PQw6EieEAgcOdkwSDQwdlzQMEkwKa3hEJkYtTmkqXYAhADyAEYAVgg6AHSkEA6GANpJALq+Fivhq+k9fTkwfgJbYaulBignq0PVBzn5hcV051DUGlX7zLVftQD0vzA6CAAMogAC2CCgfFIRTsRygczo6TUOVoUA01DAMAeRXo7GYQA):

```
const left = { a: 1, ignored: 5};
const right = { a: 2, ignored: 6, id: 18 };

function leftToRight<T>(left: Partial<T>, right: T, keys: Array<keyof T>) {
  let changed = false;
  
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (!Object.is(left[key], right[key])) {
      right[key] = left[key]!;
      changed = true;
    }
  }

  // doSomething(right.id)

  return changed
}
```

Comment: That seems to work if I go with: `function leftToRight<T extends {id: number}>(left: Partial<T>, right: T, keys: Array<keyof T>)`. Any idea how to avoid the non-null assertion?

Comment: No sure what your motivations for avoiding the non-null assertion is so I don't know if this is any better, but you could cast `left` as `T`. Example: `right[key] = (left as T)[key]`

Comment: I'd like to avoid complains from my linter ;-) and situations where errors are detected at runtime that could have been detected during compilation (in strict null checking mode). In this case, that `left[key]` is undefined and as a consequence right[key] will be undefined which could lead to problems if subsequent code doesn't expect that. However, that is probably a academic problem. So, thanks for your answer. It does what it should :)